# What is the default value of dart non-nullable variables declared with late keyword?

Tags: flutter, dart

Before null-safety, we know that if we declare variable like this

```
int a;
```

Then `a` is pointing to a null object.

But, now with sound null safety, when we declare the **non-nullable** variable with **late** keyword like this,

```
late int b;
```

Then, what is the value in `b` ? or in other words, `b` is pointing to what ?

Comment: Assuming you meant to use `late int b;`, then `b` is not observably pointing to anything.  You cannot read from `b` until you have assigned it a value.

Comment: Put another way: this is like asking "If a tree falls in the woods but no one is around to hear it, does it make a sound?" You should not care what `b` points to because you cannot observe its value.

Comment: @jamesdlin I received the reply in google-dart group. According to them, when non-nullable late variable is declared, then by the time the variables gets initialized, it is not pointing (having reference) to anything.

Comment: That's equivalent to what I said.

Answer (score 1):

The `late` keyword means that you are going to define new value as soon as possible, but you definitely will, so if you won't set any value to and use it, it will through an exception like this:

```
LateInitializationError: Field 'b' has not been initialized.
```

So it does not mean that `b` is null when you use it, it means that although it is null now it will get value very soon before you use `b`.

Comment: Your first statement `So it does not mean that b is null right now` and second statement `it means that although it is null now`  are exactly opposite to each other. So, could you please elaborate a bit more? I just want to know, if we declare non-nullable variable with late keyword, then is it pointing to null by the time the variables gets initialized ?

Comment: when you define it like late int b; it is null but before you use it you need to initialized it. so at the time that you define the variable it is null but when you use it it isn't null because you are sure you initialized it before. @Israr

Comment: So, in short we can conclude like this '`When we declare a variable with late keyword then that variable points (or stores reference) to Null object by the time we initialize that variable and we must initialize that variable before using it else we will get runtime error.`'

Comment: @Israr Yes that is right.

Answer (score 0):

please check here
`late` keyword is used initialise soon. so you need check that data is null or not. if it's null means you should initialise or assign

```
late int N;
print(N ?? 123); // checking N is null if it null means by default  assign the 123.
```

Comment: Could you send me any reference that can support your answer? Because, as far as I know, if we have something like this, `int? n` then only `print(n??123)` makes some sense.

Comment: https://www.fluttercampus.com/guide/225/null-check-operator-used-on-a-null-value/ please check